# Angular MatDialog event type

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to get the Element of clicked element when using Angular Material MatDiaog component

I don't find the type of the `event` sent to the openDialog function

```
<rect appHighlight (click)="openDialog($event)" id="container-5" data-name="container" width="12" height="12" transform="translate(242.67 381.62)" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0)"/>
```

in TS

openDialog(event:): void {
 }

When I console.log `event` I get this format

```
{type: null, content: MouseEvent}
```

I checked in matDialog [page](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) but I don't find it.

What the type of `{type: null, content: MouseEvent}`  ?

Comment: have you tried to use a [templateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef), then passing that ref into the `openDialog`?

Comment: can you provide more code or a stackblitz project?